# How to calculate the remaining time for a device to power down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I've searched a lot on stackoverflow/google/apple reference, but couldn't find the answer, I'm building a utility app and I want to show the estimated time before the device powers down, I know there isn't any API for that, so should I capture a **NSDate** whenever the battery level change and calculate the intervals between two **NSDate**s and multiply it by the remaining battery level?

But in this case, if the battery is on level 100 it won't show any estimated time,
please help if there is any other way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on your algorithm on how you want to calculate the remaining battery time, you can't determine how long it is when you have only 100% start-up battery level.

Then I would suggest you simply to display the officially announced max battery lifetime for a particular device from Apple. And then, whenever you have a battery level change perform your calculations accordingly.

Comment: But doesn't the healthiness of the battery affect the max battery life time? That may make a big difference between the 100 and 99 percent

Comment: Sure, but you don't have an official way to detect it. Your only option is to use the official numbers from Apple.